# Scrapy ordering guarantees

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there an ordering guarantees for items emitted by spider and processed by pipelines.

In other words, if my spider yields items: `item1, item2, item3` from it's `parse` method, is there a guarantee that my pipeline will process items in the same order (`item1, item2, item3`)?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of **yield**. When you do

```
    yield Request(..........)
```

requests will be sent unordered. If you want order than make sure you are sending these requests using return statement.
E.g:

1. return single request
2. after extracting item return next request.